Bondal-Orlov' theorem for noncommutative projective schemes
My question is very simple.
Is Bondal-Orlov's theorem known for noncommutative projective schemes in the sense of Artin and Zhang?
The commutative version is the following :
Let $X, Y$ be smooth projective varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ with (anti-)ample canonical sheaves. If $D^b(\text{Coh}(X)) \simeq D^b(\text{Coh}(Y))$, then $X \simeq Y$.
Any comment is welcome. Thank you!
Edit1 :
To be precise, I want to know whether the following claim is true or not:
Claim :
Let $\text{qgr}(A), \text{qgr}(B)$ be a smooth noncommutative projective scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ (+ appropriate assumptions).
We assume that $\text{qgr}(A), \text{qgr}(B)$ have (anti-)canonical sheaves.
Then, $D^b(\text{qgr}(A)) \simeq D^b(\text{qgr}(B)) \Rightarrow \text{qgr}(A) \simeq \text{qgr}(B)$.
Here, we define the smoothness of $\text{qgr}(A) $ by using its global dimension.
Canonical sheaves and ampleness are defined in papers by Artin-Zhang, Yekutieli-Zhang,  or Van den Bergh (or some other authors).
I want to use the notions, but I may need to be careful...
(The Bondal-Orlov theorem is so well-known that I thought there were some previous studies in the noncommutative case. However, I couldn't find them anywhere, so I asked here. )
Edit2 :
There is a problem. The Serre $D^b(\text{qgr}(A)) $ functor is given by tensoring with some shifts of the balanced dualizing complex $R_A$ (if exists). However, it seems that whether $R_A$ becomes a sheaf in $\text{qgr}(A)$, in general, is not known.
The appendix of De Naeghel-Van den Bergh provides details of Serre functors of noncommutative projective schemes.
Edit3 :
By the way, is the reconstruction theorem true in the case of Deligne-Mumford (or Artin) stacks?
As generalizations of the original theorem, the reconstruction theorem is proved in relative, twisted or singular cases. (Ballard, Calabrese, Sancho de Salas)
According to the introduction in Calabrese-Groechenig, we may need some good assumptions...

Is there a notion of canonical sheaf or ampleness for these spaces that you have in mind ?

The notion of canonical sheaves or a description of Serre functors is given by Yekutieli-Zhang or Van den bergh. The notion of ampleness (of functors) is given by Artin-Zhang. I will use these notions and facts.

It's not clear to me what a good answer looks like for you: with no honest spaces X and Y, I'm not sure what conclusion will be your target. At the risk of self-promotion, in a paper of mine with Cooney we aggregated a number of results in this area for noncommutative P^n's, which is probably close to the boundary of what is known outside of very particular examples. This is https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06383 - if you have any questions, feel free to contact me directly.

@JanGrabowski My guess is that Walterfield would like to conclude that derived equivalence implies an equivalence of noncomm P^n's by which I guess one can mean Morita eq or plain category eq? You have to bypass the construction of the spaces in the classical theorem but for sure one gets an equivalence of abelian categories of coherent sheaves.

@AT0 Thank you for the supplement.It seems that some different methods are needed in the noncommutative case.

@JanGrabowski Thank you for sharing your paper with me. I have added some details in the edit.

The Bondal-Orlov theorem is so well-known that I thought there were some previous studies in the noncommutative case. However, I couldn't find them anywhere, so I asked here.

@JanGrabowski For me a good answer looks like this: if A, B are triangulated categories of particular kind, and there's an equivalence, then there's also an equivalence which preserves a t-structure of derived type.

What is "a t-structure of derived type"?

I believe that, following https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06470v2, the right person to ask is Blake Farman.

Thank you. I think that if the problem in Edit 2 is solved, then we can give the answer to the question by using results of Ballard-Farman.
